# Program goes to a while loop before second cin

Tags: c++, while-loop, cin

I have a problem with 2 cins before a while loop in C++. I want them both to only take numbers greater than 0. The problem is that if I give r a value other than a number, this is what happens:

```
Radius: a
Height: Wrong radius. Input a number bigger than 0.
Radius: 7
Wrong height. Input a number bigger than 0.
Height: 10
r=7
h=10
```

(it doesn't ask for value of h before loop). For negative numbers it is fine and the program won't go to loop before getting value of height if I make radius -1 for example.

This is my code:

```
int r;
int h;
cout << "Radius: ";
cin >> r;
cout << "Height: ";
cin >> h;
while (cin.fail() || !(r > 0) || !(h > 0)) {
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    if (!(r > 0)) {
        cout << "Wrong radius. Input a number bigger than 0.\nRadius: ";
        cin >> r;
    }
    else {
        cout << "Wrong height. Input a number bigger than 0.\nHeight: ";
        cin >> h;
    }
```

Comment: The incorrect input is being left in the stream, so it gets read by `cin >> h` instead of waiting for the next input.

Comment: You need to validate the radius input *before* asking for height.

Comment: Either that, or read each with `getline()`, and parse them after reading both.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I managed to fix it by adding `cin.clear();cin.ignore()` after `cin >> r;`. Guess it's fine too? Didn't learn about getline() yet.

Comment: If you do that, you won't be able to tell if `cin >> r;` succeeded or failed.

Comment: @lotsOfSnow Saying you didn't learn about something yet hardly seems a valid argument after someone points the function out to you. Here's `getline`'s documentation: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline.

Comment: Ok, I see that a negative value is assigned to the variable when it gets something other than an int as input so  `cin.fail();` isn't needed but it still falls under remaining conditions. For this program it won't matter but I'll use `getline()` next time.